# Ticks don't display on Y-Axis of Histogram when using PlotRange

Tags: histograms, ticks

I have a histogram, if I create it without specifying the `PlotRange` it works fine and the ticks on the Y-Axis are displayed

```
Histogram[{myData}, {10000}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image]

However if I indicate the `PlotRange` they vanish

```
Histogram[{myData}, {10000}, PlotRange -> {{0, 200000}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

I tried setting the `Ticks` manually:

```
Histogram[{myData}, {10000}, PlotRange -> {{0, 200000}, Automatic}, 
          Ticks -> {{0, 50000, 100000, 150000, 200000}, 
                    {0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700}}]
```

but *Mathematica* stubbornly refused to display them.
Does anyone know how fix this?

Comment: I noticed, oddly, that if I leave out the bin width argument `{10000}` then I don't have this problem

Comment: I also noticed that this does not happen with smaller data sets

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `PlotRange->{{0,x},Automatic}` to display your data from 0 till $x$, you can use `PlotRange->{{All,x},All}` or `PlotRange->{{Automatic,x},All}`. The plot then includes the ticks and labels on the $y$-axis, and the PlotRange `All` ensures that it extends sufficiently high, as in this example:

```
mydata = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], 10^4];
Histogram[mydata, PlotRange -> {{All, 5}, All}]
```

[image: histogram with PlotRange and y axis ticks and marks]

This works independently of whether you indicate the bins or not.

Comment: Another option is to keep OP's plot range spec, but add the option `AxesOrigin->{0,0}`. Which removes the small gap between the histogram bar and the axis. This is just a stylistic choice though. +1